# I am looking for a good introductory text on the MPI

Tags: mpi, parallel-processing

I am getting ready to do some research in parallel computing next semester, and I'd love to have the MPI down pat by the start of the school year. However, the top-ranked hits on Amazon are very old, the newest being from 1999. Are there any more modern texts? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MPI2 standard came out in 1999, so the age of the books isn't a worry.   (MPI-3 is just around the corner, but it will be some time before any texts reflect this.)  I usually give my students what I consider the standard books; [Using MPI, 2nd ed](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/usingmpi/) and [Using MPI-2](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/usingmpi2/index.html).  They're authoratiative, and fairly well written.

Answer (score 1):

This one is the one that I have, and I am quite fond of it:

[http://www.amazon.com/Parallel-Programming-C-MPI-OpenMP/dp/0072822562](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072822562)

It is pretty much the same age as the ones you found (2003), but MPI did not change much over that time period.

Comment: Has it changed much since the above was written?

Comment: @pg1989, not much has changed, and even if something *had* changed, it probably wouldn't affect you too much when you are first learning (changes tend to occur at the fringe of the API, not the core).